# Can the intersection of two non subspace subsets be a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I feel as though it cannot, but I'm having difficulty explaining why.

Comment: It certainly can. Let $V=\{0\}\cup A$ and $W=\{0\}\cup B$, where $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $0\notin A,B$, and $A,B$ not subspaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within $\mathbb{R}^1$, let $S=\{0,1\}$ while $T=\{0,2\}$.  Neither is a subspace, but their intersection is $\{0\}$, which is a subspace.

For a less silly example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $S=\{(a,b):a\ge b\}$, and $T=\{(a,b):a\le b\}$.  Neither is a subspace, but their intersection is $\{(a,a):a\in \mathbb{R}\}$, which is a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

In 3-space, imagine a line through the origin (certainly a subspace). Now imagine two different wavy surfaces that pass through that line. Like two pieces of wavy aluminum roofing material oriented at 90 degrees with each other.